# Office365 send mail endpoint not working

Tags: office365, office365-apps, office365api, office365-restapi

The following request:

> POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/sendMail

Fails with the following message:
400 Unsupported segment type

The request is the same as the sample found in the Microsoft page:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/office-365-unified-api-in-depth

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the actual error message you get ? A detailed error message can tell you what is not correct with your request if you are using a client tool such as fiddler. You can also test out your request in o365 sandbox tool:  https://apisandbox.msdn.microsoft.com/

Comment: Thanks Mostafa. Yeah I know about fiddler and their sandbox playground tool. However, I cannot make sense of the error I am getting.
Here's what I get:
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Unsupported segment type.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "d964a86d-a4a0-4f72-93eb-0b9e26e0b28b",
      "date": "2015-11-17T10:31:16"
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an issue with the API, it has an open issue/ticket in GitHub. Please follow up on below link when they fix this issue.

https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-Angular-Unified-API-Connect/issues/3

Hope this helps.